# Javascript Shows an Error on Button Click

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

On my website, I have a button which when clicked, opens up a new window but gives the error "Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server. Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

$link is the website's link that I want to open. Below is the code for HTML and JavaScript.

```
<button onclick="openInNewTab('$link')" class="open-app-btn js-set-active-iframe js-create-window" data-app-url="<?php echo $link ?>">Open <?php echo $title ?>
</button>

<script> 
    function openInNewTab(url) {
        window.open('$link', '_blank', 'toolbar=0,location=0,menubar=0');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: So 404 means url is not valid so what is wrong with it?

Comment: Why is `window.open('$link',` <-- not `window.open(url, ...`

Comment: onclick="openInNewTab('$link')". Shouldn't it be onclick="openInNewTab('<?php echo $link ?>')"  ?

Comment: I replaced the code as below: 
```<script> 
    function openInNewTab(url) {
        window.open('$link', '_blank', 'toolbar=0,location=0,menubar=0');
    }
</script> ```

This does not work either. $link is the parameter that gets the website URL

Comment: @Saadi - Got you! Thanks bro! How about the $link on the Javascript? Does that need any changes?

Comment: Yes, that should be url:  window.open(url, '_blank', 'toolbar=0,location=0,menubar=0');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the onclick to

`onclick="openInNewTab('<?php echo $link ?>')"`

and then the function to:

```
<script> 
    function openInNewTab(url) {
        window.open(url, '_blank', 'toolbar=0,location=0,menubar=0');
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
<a href="<?php echo $link ?>" target="_blank" class="open-app-btn js-set-active-iframe js-create-window" data-app-url="<?php echo $link ?>">Open <?php echo $title ?></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue sorted. Thank you for the suggestions. However, 2 windows are opening up. One loads the right URL and the other shows the 404 error mentioned as above.